# Facebook Shared albums on SDK

Tags: facebook, sdk

Is there any documentation for [Shared Albums](https://www.facebook.com/help/151724461692727/) on Facebook SDK? Is it possible to know if this feature is usable with SDK on an external app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no separate SDK for Shared Albums (as of now).

After checking out the information on the page shared by you, I don't think there's much difference between a Shared Album and a normal album. I think that the way it works is that on adding a person as a contributor to an album, it simply gives that person access to upload pictures in that album.

Now, in order to check whether a person is a contributor to an album or not, you can simply use `can_upload` field as mentioned in the [Album Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/), which simply determines whether or not a particular user can upload pictures in a particular album.

Comment: Yeah but i need this feature because i have to do 2 things in my app with facebook, essentially: 1) give in automatic, after a request, the possibility to publish on a shared album and 2) the possibility to upload on this album. Can i do it?

Comment: No, I don't think you can do it by using the current API as there's no feature mentioned in the guide to add a user to an album.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Set Up SDK On your Project. 
Using Graph API, You can publish post, albums, ... and so on.

Comment: I know i can post photo and post, but shared albums is a "new" facebook feature, from August 28th you can upload photo on fan page's and friend's albums.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't think that. I read some document on Javascript SDK. The function you want to do doesn't exist there.